# Cannot resolve symbol 'service_container'

Tags: symfony

I am trying to change namespace of few bundles in a Symfony2 application. After renaming of a specific bundle, I got this error each time I run "app/console" command:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
The service "service_a" has a dependency on a non-existent service "service_b".
```

but service_b exists:

```
    <service id="service_b" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Services\ServiceName">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </service>
```

but service_container is not found. PHPStorm tells "Cannot resolve symbol 'service_container'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it worked before renaming, it looks like your DependencyInjection extension isn't being discovered.

After you renamed the bundle you most probably forgot to rename DependencyInjection extension.

Make sure it's file and class name match default convention, eg: for bundle `MyCustomBundle` you should have `MyCustomExtension.php` file in `DependencyInjection` directory in that bundle. Inside of that file, class `MyCustomExtension` should be declared under namespace `My\CustomBundle\DependencyInjection`.

Comment: You should not inject the `service_container` in your services. In your example you should rather inject only the services you need instead. See for example the "Avoiding your Code Becoming Dependent on the Container" section of http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html.

Comment: @Tsounabe That is completely unrelated to the question. While I agree that in most cases you don't want to inject your container, sometimes injecting it is perfectly fine and good way to go. Eg. when you're creating service locator services.

Comment: Indeed it is not directly related to the question but it is related to the code of the question. I've added this comment because like you say "in most cases you don't want to inject your container".